# How can I convert hh:mm:ss to float in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

```
SELECT SUM(render) AS total FROM mytable
```

This is my code for getting the summation of all rendered hrs. But the output turned out to be like for instance I have 04:30:00 and 03:15:00, then the output turned to 074520, but I want it to be like 7.75 hrs

Comment: What is the type of the `render` column? What DBMS do you use? Please add the appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: render is a time type of column Sir, sorry about the tag

Comment: I even use DATEPART() CONVERT() and CAST() but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(HOUR(render) * 60.0 + MINUTE(render)) / 60.0 AS TotalHours
FROM mytable
```

The expression `HOUR(render) * 60.0 + MINUTE(render)` converts `time` value into the number of minutes which we sum up to get the total.

You can add `SECOND()` to the formula to get a more precise answer if you want.

Comment: I actually use this method but using the DATEPART function, but this one work better. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum a time type in MySQL, use:

```
select sum(time_to_sec(render))
from mytable;
```

This converts the time to a seconds value, sums the value,  Then, if you want to convert it back to another format, convert the seconds:

```
select sum(time_to_sec(render)) / (60 * 60) as decimal_hours,
       sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(render))) as time_format
```

MySQL does not directly sum time values.  It is going to convert them to a number of the form HHMMSS.  So, `00:00:55` is `55`.  If you add it to itself you get `110`, which has nothing to do with `00:01:50`.